# Symfony 4 FOSUserBundle Custom Routes - Add prefix and subpages

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

Building an app using Symfony 4 and FOSUserBundle.

(User's profile UI is a set of tabs.)

I want to have a sub-route for each tab in the profile, so each tab is on it's own page/route.

*eg myapp.com/profile/dashboard*

*eg myapp.com/profile/bookings*

**What are the basic steps to do this?**

PS What if I wanted to drop the "/profile" part of the route:

*eg myapp.com/dashboard*

or use a dynamic one such as the user account number "/11123"

*eg myapp.com/11123/dashboard*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no special steps. You can totally ignore FOS routes by just **commenting** its definition inside `config/routes/fos_user.yaml`:

```
#fos_user:
#    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

you may also ignore some parts (comment it out) and use other parts of FOS routes:

```
#fos_user_profile:
#    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /security

fos_user_login:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
    prefix: /security
```

then just put your own routes inside `config/routes/annotations.yaml`:

```
/myapp.com/profile/dashboard/
/myapp.com/profile/bookings/
```

and process it as you wish. If you need to override FOS controllers, then check this:

[Overriding Default FOSUserBundle Controllers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html)